# How to see the compilation platform of a static library file

Tags: c, macos, unix

I had a static library file. How can I see whether it is compiled in i386 or in arm platform. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer then - unbeknownst to many (though you, as a programmer, probably do know) Mac OS X is a fullblown Unix system :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Unix (and similar - say, Linux or Minix) systems, you can use the "file" utility:

```
%file /lib/libc.so.7
libc.so.7: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (FreeBSD), dynamically linked, stripped
```

(the `%` indicates a shell prompt and is not part of the command)

As for Windows, I don't know if there is a built-in command already present, but if not, you can find the utility on this page: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html (the `file` package is about 1/3 down the page).

EDIT: For static libraries (`.a` files), you first need to extract them and check a `.o` file:

```
%cp /usr/lib/libchipmunk.a .
%ar -x libchipmunk.a
%file *.o
chipmunk.c.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (FreeBSD), not stripped
<snip>
```

**WARNING:** `ar -x ...` will pollute the local directory, so *be sure to copy the files somewhere else (say `/tmp/something`) first!*

I'm sure there is a way to directly check into these files, but this works just as well!

Comment: file command does not give that much information for a static library (.a files).

Answer (score 19):

`objdump` is your friend ;)

```
$ objdump -f lib/lib.a
```

Comment: Thanks :-D  just simply than copying file, then archiving it, and finally using `file`.

Comment: objdump is better because the output of file can be a bit limited.

Answer (score 1):

Use `file` or `objdump`. `file` always works but `objdump` will give you more detailed information about libraries and archives and executables.

Answer (score 0):

`file` gives you general information about the platform on linux.

e.g.

```
file /usr/lib/libfoo.a
```

or for a executable binary

```
file `which foo`
```

Answer (score 0):

For libraries linked to iOS apps, here's how to see the architectures of a .a file:

```
file /path/to/library.a
```

Example output for a lib built for armv7, armv7s (iPhone 5), arm64, x86_64, and i386:

```
/path/to/library.a: Mach-O universal binary with 5 architectures: [i386:Mach-O object i386] [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64] [arm_v7:Mach-O object arm_v7] [arm_v7s:Mach-O object arm_v7s] [arm64]
/path/to/library.a (for architecture i386):    Mach-O object i386
/path/to/library.a (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64
/path/to/library.a (for architecture armv7):   Mach-O object arm_v7
/path/to/library.a (for architecture armv7s):  Mach-O object arm_v7s
/path/to/library.a (for architecture arm64):   Mach-O 64-bit object arm64
```